# How to fetch the Join Properties using ODI 11g SDK

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, sdk, oracle-data-integrator

I am using ODI 11g SDK to read interfaces. After getting the Join collection using the below code:

```
Collection<Join> joins = dataset.getJoins();
```

I can only check if a join in the collection is a Cross join, Natural join, Left Outer or Right Outer, but in the ODI tool I can set the Join as Inner or Full as well which I am not able to detect using the SDK.

I tried searching the SDK for some other class or function but nothing seems to give these details.

Can any one please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use isOuter1() and isOuter2().

- If they both return true, it's a full outer join.
- If they both return false it's an inner join.
- If the first one returns true and the second false, it's a left outer join
- If the first one returns false and the second true, it's a right outer join

Similarly you can use setOuter1() and setOuter2() to change the type of join.
More details : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/apirefs.1111/e17060/toc.htm

Comment: Thanks Jerome, I can use these conditinos to write the code. Also, If both are false, then it can be a cross join or natural join also and hence a check is required for that too.

Comment: A cross join is just an inner join with a joining condition always true.
For the natural Join, this is something different. It's just another syntax but it can be left outer, right outer or inner : https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljnaturaljoin.html